# Port open, but not listening

Tags: docker, rhel7

I'm trying to open a random port, so that a docker container can bind to it.

sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=27000/tcp       # success

sudo firewall-cmd --reload       # success

sudo netstat -tunap | grep -i listen     # port 27000 doesn't show up

sudo lsof -i :27000      # No process is using port 27000

curl -v `hostname`:27000    # Failed connect to; connection refused

How can I open a port and make it listen.
Thank you

Comment: Already have one container port map to 27000? Didn't see it in question.

Comment: There is no container that is running on port 27000. I did not run a container yet. I would run, once I'm assured that port is open and listening

Comment: `firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=27000/tcp` just open exception in firewall to let traffic pass through, you need open port first before `curl`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, even though, the command you mention ran successfully, but, the port is not listening

Comment: Port will not listen unless you have application open this port.

Comment: oh I see. So, should I mention a service when opening up a port, like this: firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=27000/tcp --service=http